# Regarding "Two Singular Diffusion Problems" by William Feller

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, statistical-mechanics

I'm currently reading the research paper, [*Two Singular Diffusion Problems*](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1969318?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21106239145251), by William Feller (1950). However, I don't understand how Feller derived the solution $(3.5)$ given equation $(3.4)$ in his research paper. More specifically, I don't understand how Feller solved $$dt=\frac{d\omega}{f(t)-cs\omega} \implies \frac{d\omega}{dt}=f(t)-cs\omega,$$ where $$\text{This is equation (3.4)}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, e^{-bt}\frac{as-b}{s}=C_1 \implies s=\frac{be^{-bt}}{ae^{-bt}-C_1},$$ and $a, b, C_1$ are constants with $b\neq0$ to get the solution$$\text{This is equation (3.5)}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \omega = \left|C_1 - ae^{-bt}\right|^{c/a}\left\{C_2 + \int_{0}^{t}{\frac{f(\tau)d\tau}{\left|C_1 - ae^{-b\tau}\right|^{c/a}}}\right\},$$ where $C_2$ is a constant as well.

Please note that I have already verified this is true by differentiating it (and using the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*) but I don't understand *how* Feller derived it originally.

Can someone please explain to me in details or give me some hints regarding this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It'd be great if you find the link that could be seen not only by registered Jstor users :) Or if you can just cite the equation 3.4 and solution 3.5 from paper.

Comment: @Evgeny , I have already cited equation (3.4) and solution (3.5) in the post. I am sorry but I don't think I can post the full paper here since I don't think I can distribute the paper online without permission from JSTOR. However, I have already given all the information regarding this issue from the paper here (I think). :)

Comment: Well, the main question was what's constant and what is not, and what is the final equation. It became much clearer now, thanks! I've posted an answer, ask if something is still unknown to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when it's known what is constant and what it's not, the key to solving this equation is observation that it's first order inhomogeneous linear equation:

$$ \frac{d\omega}{dt} + c \left (\frac{be^{-bt}}{ae^{-bt}-C_1} \right) \cdot \omega = f(t) $$

General solution of this ODE is a linear combination of any solution of it and general solution of corresponding homogeneous linear ODE:

$$ \frac{d\omega}{dt} + c \left (\frac{be^{-bt}}{ae^{-bt}-C_1} \right) \cdot \omega = 0 $$

Rewriting your already known solution:

$$ \omega = \color{blue}{ C_2\cdot \left|C_1 - ae^{-bt}\right|^{c/a}}  + \color{green}{\left|C_1 - ae^{-bt}\right|^{c/a} \cdot \int_{0}^{t}{\frac{f(\tau)d\tau}{\left|C_1 - ae^{-b\tau}\right|^{c/a}}}} $$
blue expression is a **general** solution to corresponding homogeneous ODE and green expression is a some solution of original ODE obtained via the method of constants variation.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I don't understand one thing: so, you first solve the homogeneous ODE to get $\omega = exp\left(\int{\frac{cb e^{-bt}}{a e^{-bt} - C_1}}\right)$, but how does this integral give you an absolute value function?

Comment: Well, it's just because $\int \frac{dz}{z}$ is $\ln \vert z \vert$ :)

Comment: Oh, now I think I understand how Feller got that solution! Thank you very much for your help. :D

Comment: You're welcome :) don't forget to accept the solution if it seems to answer your questions.

Comment: I have another question: Once you get the general solution $\left|C_1 - ae^{-bt}\right|^{c/a}$, you multiply it throughout the original ODE and use the "reverse" product rule to get: $$\frac{d}{dt}\left[\left|C_1 - ae^{-bt}\right|^{c/a}\omega\right]=\left|C_1 - ae^{-bt}\right|^{c/a}f(t)$$ _(Please see next comment for continuation.)_

Comment: and integrating both sides and solve for $\omega$ to get $$\omega = \frac{\int_{0}^{t}{\left|C_1 - ae^{-b\tau}\right|^{c/a}f(\tau)\,d\tau}}{\left|C_1 - ae^{-bt}\right|^{c/a}}$$ as the particular solution which is not the same as your particular solution (in green). Can you please let me know where I did wrong?

Comment: I think you got variation of constants slightly wrong. When you found general solution of homogeneous equation in form $C \cdot \mathcal{F}(t)$ then you are guessing particular solution of inhomogeneous equation in form $C(t) \cdot \mathcal{F}(t)$. Plug it in the original equation and you'll get something like $C^\prime (t) \mathcal{F}(t) = f(t)$.